# Is there any way to exploit extra iCloud storage space beyond the size of my SSD?

Tags: macos, icloud, ssd, storage

I have a Macbook with a 500GB hard drive, but I pay for [the 2TB tier of iCloud storage](https://www.apple.com/icloud/#compare-plans).

I'm imagining things like a virtual drive where I could park rarely used files, similar to a photostream which includes photos that aren't in my Photos library. Or something like Google Drive, where I can put things and get them back as needed.

Is iCloud strictly and permanently tied to the contents of my actual computer or is there any way to use the extra 1.5TB of storage?

**UPDATE**: I realize I wasn't clear. I don't want to use "optimize storage".

Without going into details, I need the files on my computer to actually be on my computer. It has to be a certainty — there can never be a doubt or a lag when I need a file.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If *all* files need to be actually (i.e. physically) on the computer, how would it be possible to have more files than what fits on your SSD?

Comment: Worth keeping in mind that iCloud is a synchronization service. You can‘t have data in iCloud which isn‘t also (at least as a stub) on your devices logged into it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what it the reason for having a 2 TB subscription if you can’t seem to use it?

Comment: I have a 2TB iMac that's my main computer, and I have a 500GB MB that I use a lot, around the house, when I'm traveling etc. I also have Photos in iCloud and iTunes Match. I wrote in a comment below that I'd like to have my daily-use files fit in 500MB so that the MB will always be up-to-date, but I have a lot of other files on my iMac that I'd like to store in iCloud as well.

Answer (score 4):

Note that iCloud Drive is not a backup. It's not another pool of storage like Google Drive.

The higher tiers of iCloud storage appear to be most useful for users with multiple devices on the same account. Thus it could hold an iPhone & iPad backup in addition to Photos, CloudKit stuff & iCloud Drive.

Optimise Local Storage will potentially replace local files with a stub file if macOS decides it needs to free up local space. If you accidentally delete the local file, it will also delete the 'proper' version of the file in iCloud Drive. You can't have a file in iCloud Drive without either the original, or a stub file, present in local storage.

Also, be aware that this has an impact on local backups. Unless your backup system is aware a local file is a stub file and downloads a copy for backup purposes (I know CCC can be configured to do this) then all you are backing up locally is fresh air (the stub).

Comment: Higher tiers are also useful for users with a lot of pictures in Photos (which they don't download in fully quality by default).

Comment: All of these things you describe seem like a very useful implementation to accomplish what the OP intends. They can upload all sorts of files to iCloud to use that space fully and not have it downloaded for a local backup or take up space as the optimize will clearly know all the content can't be instantiated locally with the math proposed. Great point on the "cloud is not a backup" and +1 for addressing the details of the implementation.

Comment: @nohillside Certainly! Photos (the app) is at least a little more robust at handling optimised images, because its design hides the stubs somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it gives me food for thought. I could potentially use iCloud storage with a family plan, and store many files via a different Apple ID on my computer using "optimize storage", while my main account would have all the files actually present. I have modified the question.

Comment: One of the issues is that I have two Macs — one has 500GB the other 2TB. The smaller Mac limits what I can keep in iCloud. I would like to keep the other 1.5TB from the bigger machine, or at least some of it, in the extra iCloud space. What I've done since yesterday is create a second account on the bigger machine called Storage, and used family sharing to include this account in the 2TB of space. So now I can easily get to the "storage" stuff on the big mac, and it's in iCloud.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly!

Just enable iCloud Drive in your Apple-ID settings and select "optimize mac storage". You can then also choose to upload e.g. your documents or desktop folder to iCloud.

Clarification: **you** choose which folders are uploaded to Drive. It is also possible to create own new folders and store those in Drive.

Comment: Thanks, but I realize I wasn't clear — I've modified the question.

Comment: I dont quite get it: you want to use that cloud storage while still having everything saved locally? How is that going to help with the limited 500GBs of your mac storage?

Comment: Everything I need to work day-to-day fits on my 500GB mac, but I have lots of other files that I could back up — family photos, music collection, archived work I've done in the past. If I can use the extra iCloud space for all that, it would be great. It would be good for security, but also to have access if I'm out somewhere and need something.

Comment: As said - *you* choose which folders and thereby which files are synced. You can totally leave everything in documents and desktop fully local, but have another folder in Drive where you store those files. Then no harm can be done to the important files, even when selecting optimize storage. The posted "solution" is complete overkill and a complfication of an existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you can upload files to iCloud from an external drive or another computer and when your Mac has "optimize storage" enabled, [it won't attempt to download all the files and fill the local drive](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102670) on your Mac or other iOS / iPadOS devices with less than 2 TB of storage available.

The system is designed to locally cache some of the content and tune what's local over time, but to have stubs of all the files that take negligible space and point to the cloud version of the full files.

When you need to grow the storage past what iCloud can deliver or don't like how Apple manages - look to a solid backup solution like [Backblaze](https://www.backblaze.com) or [Arq](https://www.arqbackup.com/) as well as a very powerful sync and file transfer product [Transmit](https://panic.com/transmit/).

As you can see Transmit and Arq don't mess with iCloud - they let Apple manage that and for most people, you won't need any of these three products to just store some files in iCloud.

Everything [Andy said is gold](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/467979/5472) - limitations of optimize, backup needs and more. Also, no to it being a drive in the sidebar separate from the main iCloud Drive location Finder already provides you but yes to everything else you ask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realize my question wasn't clear. I wanted to know if there was a way to use extra iCloud storage WITHOUT using optimize storage.

Comment: Not that I can think of @AndySwift but it’s really not bad with optimize on in my experience. You’ll have to decide if funding other storage is worth the freedom to have it separate than the integrated offering Apple provides.

Comment: It doesn't work for me because I have Github repositories and some other similar things where the basic functionality is completely dependent on the files actually being present on the computer.

Comment: Hmm - no cloud backed solution will work for that case @AndySwift since you can’t store files when you’re out of room. You’ll need to add external storage or move other things to iCloud to let them be evicted for that to work.

Comment: Well, that's my whole question — can I keep the stuff that won't fit on my HD in iCloud. I have access to other computers, accounts etc.

Comment: Sorry Andy. I can’t reconcile how “the files actually being present on the computer” works with “cloud only storage”.  Those to me are mutually exclusive. Let’s hope someone else can get you a better answer if mine doesn’t make sense or isn’t useful.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing:

- I enabled **Family Sharing** for my Apple ID
- I created a new **Apple ID**, and invited it to use Family Sharing

Now I have two accounts:

- my **main account** that has frequently used files, and does *not* use Optimize Storage
- a **second account** on the same computer, that has rarely used files and *does* use Optimize Storage

To pass files back and forth, I use the **Shared** folder in **/Users**.

This gives me the ability to use all of my 2TB of iCloud storage on a 500MB Macbook, while being able to guarantee that frequently-used files are actually on the disk, and not just in iCloud.

Comment: Creative and for sure this works, but not necessary. See my comment above! I can see that this is now a viable solution for you, but I would think in general its an easier way having just one Apple-ID and organizing docs in one account.